# how to dynamically display widgets add to a QVBoxLayout pyside6

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer, pyside6, qvboxlayout

hi I’m designing a python project to practice a YouTube playlist downloader.
for this I use python3 and pyside6 as a graphical interface but since a few hours I have a problem:

when I perform functions that take time (like searching for the url of a youtube playlist)
freezes the entire interface until the processing is done so no access to the other components is possible.

but once the processing completes the function returns a number of widget-like component numbers from a class (videoGenerer) that inherits the widget component itself
and which are all added to a QVBoxLayout type element with the addWidget() method (self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(videoGenerer)) and then displayed on the screen.

disadvantages: the graphical interface remains frozen for a while waiting for the end of the method but I have my elements added in my QVBoxLayout (self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(videoGenerer)) and
visible on screen

The code is:

```
import os
import sys
import threading
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtUiTools import loadUiType
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from pytube import Playlist
from pytube.exceptions import PytubeError

from composant.conteneurDeVideo import conteneurDeVideo

path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.ui")
Form, _ = loadUiType(path)


class main(QMainWindow, Form):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # ------------ commencer en dessou -----------
        self.setWindowTitle("PlayList")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icons/_active__web.png"))
        self.resize(1200, 600)

        self.btnRechercher.clicked.connect(self.threadMethode)

    def threadMethode(self):
        threadRecherchePlaylist = threading.Thread(target=self.recherchePlaylist())
        threadRecherchePlaylist.start()

    def recherchePlaylist(self):

        self.txtUrl: str = self.editUrl.text()
        self.videosPlaylist = Playlist(self.txtUrl.strip())

        for video in self.videosPlaylist.videos:
            try:

                print(threading.active_count())
                print(threading.enumerate())

                videoGenerer = conteneurDeVideo(video)

                self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(videoGenerer)

            except PytubeError:
                print("impossible de recuperer cette video...")

        print("elemment ajouter ", self.verticalLayout_6.count())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = main()
    w.show()  # show window
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

to solve my screen problem freeze I told myself better to put this function in another thread to not block the main thread
and since all is done correctly I even checked the two threads are executed I am no longer the GUI freeze and all my elements
are always added in my QVBoxLayout with the addWidget() method (I checked it too) but this time I no longer have any visible elements on the screen
and I have no errors in the console either

The code is:

```
import os
import sys
import threading
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtUiTools import loadUiType
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from pytube import Playlist, YouTube
from pytube.exceptions import PytubeError

from composant.conteneurDeVideo import conteneurDeVideo

path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.ui")
Form, _ = loadUiType(path)


class main(QMainWindow, Form):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # ------------ commencer en dessou -----------
        self.setWindowTitle("PlayList")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icons/_active__web.png"))
        self.resize(1200, 600)

        self.btnRechercher.clicked.connect(self.threadMethode)

    def threadMethode(self):

        self.txtUrl: str = self.editUrl.text()
        self.videosPlaylist = Playlist(self.txtUrl.strip())

        def recherchePlaylist():
            for video in self.videosPlaylist.videos:
                try:

                    print("nbr des thread activer", threading.active_count())
                    print("liste de thread active", threading.enumerate())

                    videoGenerer = conteneurDeVideo(video)

                    self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(videoGenerer)

                except PytubeError:
                    print("impossible de recuperer cette video...")

            print("elemment ajouter ", self.verticalLayout_6.count())

        threadRecherchePlaylist = threading.Thread(target=recherchePlaylist, args=())
        threadRecherchePlaylist.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = main()
    w.show()  # show window
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

the class (videoGenerer) that returns the widgets:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtUiTools import loadUiType
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from pytube import YouTube

path = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "conteneurDeVideo.ui")
Form, _ = loadUiType(path)


class conteneurDeVideo(QWidget, Form):

    def __init__(self, video: YouTube, parent=None):
        super(conteneurDeVideo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # ------------ commencer en dessou -----------

        self.video = video

        txt: QLabel = self.label
        txt.setText(video.title)

    def pourcent(self, stream, chunk, byte_remaning):
        nbr = stream.filesize - byte_remaning
        print("progress", int(nbr * 100 / stream.filesize), "%")

    def telecharger(self):
        self.video.register_on_progress_callback(self.pourcent)
        tag_de_telechargement = self.video.streams.get_by_itag(22)

        print("telechargement lancer...")
        chemins = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop", "youVideo")
        os.makedirs(chemins, exist_ok=True)
        tag_de_telechargement.download(chemins)
```

I have no idea to display them on the screen without freezing the entire interface (do not block the main thread) do you have any solutions to offer me?

Comment: Start by considering that UI elements are **not** thread safe. Accessing (or creating) them is unsafe or just forbidden. If you need to use a separate thread and communicate with the main one, the only way to achieve that is by using QThread and custom signals, which would then be connected to the functions that would eventually manipulate and/or access UI elements. Please do some research on the subject, as there's plenty of resource on the topic.